# How can I create a highlight effekt for item in list?

Tags: flutter

I want to create a list where a user can hold down a button on the list item, and then that item gets highlighted in a way that the rest of the screen becomes dark and transparent (Example below)

How do I achieve this highlighting? I tried looking into masks, but not sure if that's the best thing.

Just a note: I want to achieve it in a way that the highlighting only happens while the user is pressing the button.

Any help that can guide me to a good direction is much appreciated!

[image: Example]

Answer (score 2):

Try this, [focused_menu](https://pub.dev/packages/focused_menu), I think listview will do too:

```
GridView(
                  physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
                  children: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]

                       // Wrap each item (Card) with Focused Menu Holder
                      .map((e) => FocusedMenuHolder(
                        menuWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.50,
                        blurSize: 5.0,
                        menuItemExtent: 45,
                        menuBoxDecoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.grey,borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15.0))),
                        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 100),
                        animateMenuItems: true,
                        blurBackgroundColor: Colors.black54,
                        openWithTap: true, // Open Focused-Menu on Tap rather than Long Press
                        menuOffset: 10.0, // Offset value to show menuItem from the selected item
                        bottomOffsetHeight: 80.0, // Offset height to consider, for showing the menu item ( for example bottom navigation bar), so that the popup menu will be shown on top of selected item.
                        menuItems: <FocusedMenuItem>[
                          // Add Each FocusedMenuItem  for Menu Options
                          FocusedMenuItem(title: Text("Open"),trailingIcon: Icon(Icons.open_in_new) ,onPressed: (){
                            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>ScreenTwo()));
                          }),
                          FocusedMenuItem(title: Text("Share"),trailingIcon: Icon(Icons.share) ,onPressed: (){}),
                          FocusedMenuItem(title: Text("Favorite"),trailingIcon: Icon(Icons.favorite_border) ,onPressed: (){}),
                          FocusedMenuItem(title: Text("Delete",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.redAccent),),trailingIcon: Icon(Icons.delete,color: Colors.redAccent,) ,onPressed: (){}),
                        ],
                        onPressed: (){},
                        child: Card(
                              child: Column(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Image.asset("assets/images/image_$e.jpg"),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                      ))
                      .toList(),
                ),
```

Comment: Thank you, for sharing! Yes it helps a lot to see this. However the 'hold' gesture gets lost because it transitions to a new page. Hoping to find a way around otherwise I have to improvise using some of this. But thank you