# How to make a mask with multiple highlights in a Flutter screen?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am not sure how to describe this scenarios, below is the screenshot about this, I want to user tap one of the card, and then highlight this card, in the meantime, two actions in the screen's bottom which user can do some actions, any help are appriciate!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to what I've answered, it's quite similar to your case

https://stackoverflow.com/a/67088035/11276416

Comment: Hi, thank you for you help, then the package 'Focused Menu' will popup the menus followed by the highlight item, but in my case, I want the actions popup to screen's bottom, which means we have multiple highlights in one screen.